# Keep getting duplicate circle

Tags: vertex-groups

Hi I am new to Blender and I am trying to select a vertex that i can then drag down on a uv mesh sphere. However I keep getting a duplicate circle. I am so frustrated bc I do not understand why this is the case when I right click and click the vertex.

Comment: Try using left click to select. In the newest version, Blender switched to left click select instead of right click.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it may be easier if you saw a video so go to this link ... if this is not what you wanted let me know.

https://youtu.be/C31vVLQxWME

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on this site.